# Dont understand Category Filter in Build Definition

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I've got 2 test categories "A" and "B". I want the build definition to ignore both of them, so I entered the following into the Category Filter:

```
!A&!B
```

Result: MSBuild will ignore all Tests marked with "A" but not the ones marked with "B". BUT: If I add "A" to the tests marked only with "B" it'll work properly.

I can't explain it better, even if I overthink it twice :-(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be obsolete because the problem does not occure in TFS 2013. They changed the syntax inside the filter. Maybe thats why?

Answer (score 2):

I believe since you are using '!' or "NOT EQUAL' you need to have an 'OR' in the not the 'AND'.

```
!A|!B
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply. Unfortunal I can't test this out because the filter has changed in TFS 2012 and I switched to this version already. I'll give you an uprate.

Comment: @sprinter252 It's the correct answer anyway. It's basic boolean logic. You wanted to exclude all A and all B but you were originally excluding tests that were both NOT A and NOT B. The | operator is correct here.